# Replace part of url and loop trough all the pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, replace

I am working on a script to scrape some pages of my online supermarket. Each page has its own number The url is as follows

```
https://www.jumbo.com/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/Jumbo-Grocery-Site/nl_NL/-/EUR/ViewOrderHistory-Paging?StatusType=Complete&PageNumber=1&PageableID=5DIKY7MVn2IAAAF5QrIGubww
```

The part where the page number is located is `Complete&PageNumber=1&PageableID` where 1 is the pagenumber. I would like the to go trough al the pages up to page thirteen (I have the max pagenumver stored in a variable PageNo)

I have been messing around with this part of code nested inside a replace function but I can't get the pieces together. The part of code below gives me the pagenumber.

```
s = url
pattern = "=Complete&PageNumber=(.*?)&PageableID="
substring = re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
print(substring)
```

I also been googling around for a bit of time but unfortunately without the desired result...Can you guys help me out again? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It seems like you can't access the page unless you have an account. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

in views file make a function and add the following

```
dic = {}
pre_url = '=Complete&PageNumber=(.*?)&PageableID='
post_url = 'whatever it is'
for i in range(1,14):
   s = pre + str(i) + post_url
   dic['url'] = s

return render(dic,template)
```

Inside the templates

```
{% for i in url %}
   <li><a href="{{i}}"></a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```

this is how you will get all the links one click away and add the new URL inside the URLs file which leads to this template

Answer (score 0):

In case the latest part of the URL "PageableID=5DIKY7MVn2IAAAF5QrIGubww" is constant so the only changing part is a number in "PageNumber=1" you can simply do the following:

```
url_tmpl = 'https://www.jumbo.com/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/Jumbo-Grocery-Site/nl_NL/-/EUR/ViewOrderHistory-Paging?StatusType=Complete&PageNumber={}&PageableID=5DIKY7MVn2IAAAF5QrIGubww'
for i in range(1,PageNo+1):
    url = url_tmpl.format(i)
    driver.get(url)
```